# How can I see the last time a program was run?

Tags: history

Is there any way I can see what programs were running at a specific time?  Is there a way to see the last time a program was run?  I'm trying to see if a certain program was running yesterday because I suspect it may have been affecting the program I was using.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Look at the access time on the program binary (but Ubuntu by default mounts with `relatime`, so this won't be accurate unless you've previously enabled it)
- Look for mentions of the program in `~/.xsession` or `/var/log/kern.log` around that time

Otherwise no.